# gfortran compiler error calling recursive log_gamma function

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I uploaded a 2F1 hypergeometric function but it turns out that it does not compile on my computer. It is from [this article](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0708.0116).  I use

```
GNU Fortran (Built by Jeroen for the R-project) 8.3.0
```

shiped with RTools 4.0. Can you figure out why it does not compile and how this could be solved? In the code below, I just kept the one line that generates the error. The error is given next.

```
MODULE HYP_2F1_MODULE
  !--------------------------------------------------------------------
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: PR=KIND(1.0D0)
  REAL(PR)     ::  ONE=1.0D0
CONTAINS
  !
END MODULE HYP_2F1_MODULE
!
!----------------------------------------------------------------------
RECURSIVE FUNCTION LOG_GAMMA(Z) RESULT(RES)

  USE HYP_2F1_MODULE
  IMPLICIT NONE
  COMPLEX(PR),INTENT(IN) :: Z
  COMPLEX(PR)  :: RES
  !
     RES = LOG_GAMMA( ONE -z);
  !
END FUNCTION LOG_GAMMA
```

Here is the error message

```
 testZ.f90:18:22:

      RES = LOG_GAMMA( ONE - Z);
                 1
Error: 'x' argument of 'log_gamma' intrinsic at (1) must be REAL
```

Comment: The error message  shown in your question doesn't match the code you've posted.

Comment: @bob just updated the code, then the error message

Comment: Well, that does not compile, and I cannot figure out why. This is taken (as is) from a NASA repository. I tried comverting ONE to a complex CMPLX(ONE, ZERO) before the subtraction, but still does not compile.

Comment: The RES of LOG_GAMMA is clearly stated as COMPLEX, so I don't understand why it says that (1) must be REAL.

Comment: Oh I see, I dod not notice the function itself is named `LOG_GAMMA`. `LOG_GAMMA` is also a Fortran 2018 intrinsic function. I wonder why the intrinsic is not shadowed here.

Comment: Shouldn't the function shadow the intrinsic?

Comment: The problem will be in the recursive attribute and the associated result clause and might be a compiler bug.

Comment: Good catch, I did not know that LOG_GAMMA was built-in. I will rename it no problem.  If you wan to turn this into an answer? Thanks.

Comment: I guess solutions include trying a newer compiler, or using -std=f95 to disable the intrinsic.

Comment: @veryreverie Very good point, for older codes `-std=f95` will work. Even `-f2003` suffices.

Comment: It seems that the correct function gets called, if the types agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Fortran 2008+ intrinsic of the same name

> 16.9.119 LOG_GAMMA (X)
> 1 Description. Logarithm of the absolute value of the gamma function.
> 2 Class. Elemental function.
> 3 Argument. X
> shall be of type real. Its value shall not be a negative integer or
> zero.

There is some sort of clash I do not completely understand here. The obvious workaround is to rename your function. What I can say is that without the result clause (which you need because of the recursive attribute) the intrinsic would be shadowed. It might be a compiler bug.

Also consider, whether the intrinsic of the same name couldn't also do what you need from your function.

Comment: It's a bug.  F2018, 15.6.2.2, page 319:
   If RESULT appears, the name of the function result of the
   function is result-name and all occurrences of the function
   name in execution-part statements in its scope refer to the
   function itself.

Comment: @steve reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105138

Comment: Thanks.  I added the cited text for F2018 to the audit trail.

Comment: A patch to fix gfortran has been submitted. See the URL for the PR @Vladimir posted.  Have no idea when, or even if, it will make into the tree.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @VladimirF's suggestions, you can add the compiler flag [`-std=f95`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html) to enforce compliance with the Fortran 95 standard. Provided you haven't added `-fall-intrinsics` this will disable all intrinsics from standards after Fortran 95, and should make the legacy code work.

Comment: Also `-std=f2003` in this case, if something from Fortran 2003 is needed.